# Getting openconnect vpn to work through gui

Tags: network-manager, vpn, cisco

I'm trying to add a vpn connection through the openconnect and using the gui. Even though it says that I am connected, I can't access any of the websites on the network I'm trying to connect to.

However, if I run this command in the terminal, I am able to access the websites.

```
sudo openconnect blah.google.blah
```

So it's probably the sudo access? How can I add that to the gui?

Comment: Same problem, Kubuntu 15.04

Comment: Same problem, Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 5):

Enable the proposed repositories

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

then you can install

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

This will allow you to configure them via the NetworkManager GUI.

Comment: (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04) - I enabled that repository, then ran the command you suggested but I get "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed". I then tried `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect/xenial-proposed network-manager-openconnect-gnome/xenial-proposed` but got `E: Release 'xenial-proposed' for 'network-manager-openconnect' was not found
E: Release 'xenial-proposed' for 'network-manager-openconnect-gnome' was not found`

Comment: 14.04 is not xenial its trusty , you need to edit  your apt configuration

Comment: Oops, you're right, but it still didn't work: `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect/trusty-proposed network-manager-openconnect-gnome/trusty-proposed

E: Release 'trusty-proposed' for 'network-manager-openconnect' was not found                                                                                             
E: Release 'trusty-proposed' for 'network-manager-openconnect-gnome' was not found`

Comment: Note that this is the line in my sources.list `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse restricted main`

Comment: just to check you have done and apt-get update since adding the new repos haven't you ?

Comment: Yes, I did. This is what I have installed: `dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep network-manager-openconnect
ii  network-manager-openconnect                           0.9.8.0-1ubuntu2                                    amd64        network management framework (OpenConnect plugin)
ii  network-manager-openconnect-gnome                     0.9.8.0-1ubuntu2                                    amd64        network management framework (OpenConnect plugin GNOME GUI)`

Comment: Any other ideas?