# Openconnect VPN stopped working

Tags: networking, vpn, openconnect

I installed openconnect when I installed Kubuntu 18.04, and I was able to connect to work just fine using

```
sudo openconnect --user <username> --juniper https://<vpn_server>
```

However since today, I've been unable to connect. When I run the command and supply my password, it tells me the connection was successful and I'm connected as some ip, using SSL.

However, nothing works! I'm not able to ssh/ping to my servers, chrome is unable to resolve internal work URLs.

Plus, my regular internet also feels slower (especially in hostname resolution).

I tried to purge any VPN related things I installed since then (windscribe-cli and openvpn), and reboot, but the situation is still the same.

I tried to manually specify the tun0 interface for ping, but I still can't reach work servers.

Edit: It's not local network/router issue, since my work macbook is able to connect and everything works fine on it.

Comment: Sounds like [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631810/getting-openconnect-vpn-to-work-through-network-manager?rq=1). Name resolution is now done in systemd-resolved by default I think, what's your `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved` say? What's your `cat /etc/resolv.conf` output when connected normally and to the VPN, where does `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`show your resolv.conf is linked to?